# Use Yii rule validation to change attribute name if form attribute value is empty

Tags: php, yii, yii-cformmodel

I have a model that extends the **Yii CFormModel** and I would like to define a **validation rule** that checks whether the attribute value is empty and - if that is the case - sets the *attribute name* to an empty string instead of changing the input value.

Is such a scenario even possible or are validation rules only intended for warnings and/or changes of the input values?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Below is the example code of my model:

```
class LoginForm extends CFormModel
{
    public $firstName;
    public $lastName;

    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('firstName, lastName', 'checkIfEmpty', 'changeAttributeName'),
        );
    }
    // some functions
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? Do you simply want to ignore all empty attributes?

Comment: Yes, I want to prevent the empty attributes from being present in the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure whether your use case is very elegant, but the following should work:

```
class LoginForm extends CFormModel
{
    public $firstName;
    public $lastName;

    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('firstName, lastName', 'checkIfEmpty'),
        );
    }

    public function checkIfEmpty($attribute, $params) 
    {
        if(empty($this->$attribute)) {
            unset($this->$attribute);
        }
    }

    // some functions
}
```

Based on hamed's reply, another way would be to use the `beforeValidate()` function:

```
class LoginForm extends CFormModel
{
    public $firstName;
    public $lastName;

    protected function beforeValidate()
    {
        if(parent::beforeValidate()) {
            foreach(array('firstName, lastName') as $attribute) {
                if(empty($this->$attribute)) {
                    unset($this->$attribute);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

CModel has [beforeValidate()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#beforeValidate-detail) method. This method call **before yii automatic model validation.** You should override it in your LoginForm Model:

```
protected function beforeValidate()
    {
        if(parent::beforeValidate())
        {

            if($this->firstname == null)
               $this->firstname = "Some String";
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: @atreju: Did you try my solution?

Comment: Yes, I did just now, thank you. I think my question was a bit too ambiguos - I need to unset the attribute instead of giving it a default value in order to make it "disappear" from the URL. But your approachcombined with vim's should work!

Answer (score 0):

You can use default rules set.

```
public function rules()
{
        return array(
           array('firstName', 'default', 'value'=>Yii::app()->getUser()->getName()),
        );
}
```

Take note that this will run at validation time, which is normally after the form has been submitted. It will not populate the form value with the default value. You can use the afterFind() method to do that.